# When is it true that $\sup g - \inf g \le 2\sup g$?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, inequality, random-variables, machine-learning

I am currently reading the first version of the paper titled ["On the Margin Theory of Feedforward Neural Networks"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.05369v1.pdf) by Colin Wei, Jason D. Lee, Qiang Liu and Tengyu Ma.

In Lemma C.4 of the appendix, the authors give upper bounds for the [Rademacher complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_complexity) of some specific function class, and there is one step in the proof they give that I fail to understand. Page 21, the authors give the following upper bound :
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right\lvert - \inf_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right\lvert\right] &\le \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i) - \inf_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] \\
&\le 2\mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right]\end{align} $$

To provide some context here, $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d. Rademacher random variables, $\mathbb S^d$ is the $d$-dimensional unit sphere, $x_i$ are elements of $\mathbb R^d$ and $\phi$ is an $M$-Lipschitz activation function.

However these details don't seem very relevant here since in the first inequality, it seems that they simply used [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330900/proving-supf-inff-leq-supf-inff) that $\sup |g| - \inf |g| \le \sup g - \inf g$.
The second inequality is quite puzzling to me because it seems to use the fact that $\sup g - \inf g \le 2\sup g$ which is equivalent to $ -\inf g \le \sup g$ and is not true in general (consider for instance $g : x \mapsto -x^2$).

I am thinking that maybe under some assumption this inequality might be true, but I can't manage to get further than this.
I would be grateful for any help in proving why the second inequality holds true.

Comment: I think this is due to the expectation. Note that $-\inf (...)=\sup(-...)$ and that the distribution of the $\epsilon_i$ is the same as the distribution of the $-\epsilon_i$.

Comment: Thank you @PhoemueX, you solved my problem. I just typed it as an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PhoemueX's comment, I give the following proof of why the inequality holds true.
We have that :
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i) - \inf_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] &= \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] - \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\inf_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] \tag1\\
&= \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] + \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[-\inf_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] \tag2 \\
&=\mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] + \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] \tag3 \\
&=\mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right] + \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-\epsilon_i) \phi(u^T x_i)\right]\tag4 \\
&=2\mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right]\tag5\end{align} $$

Here, lines (1) and (2) are using the linearity of expectation.
To go from (2) to (3) we use the fact that $-\inf(g) = \sup(-g)$ for any real-valued function $g$. $(\star) $
Finally, to get from (4) to (5) we use the fact that $(\epsilon_i)$ and $(-\epsilon_i)$ are identically distributed and thus $$ \mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-\epsilon_i) \phi(u^T x_i)\right] = \mathbb E_{(-\epsilon_i)}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-\epsilon_i) \phi(u^T x_i)\right] =\mathbb E_{\epsilon_i}\left[\sup_{u\in\mathbb S^d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i \phi(u^T x_i)\right]\,\,\blacksquare $$

Now for the sake of completeness, I also give a quick proof of $(\star)$ :

> **Lemma :** For any real-valued function $g$, $-\inf(g) = \sup(-g)$

**Proof :** By definition, $\inf(g) \le g(x)\,\,\, \forall x$ and thus $-\inf(g) \ge -g(x)\,\,\, \forall x $ as well, so $-\inf(g)$ is an upper bound of $-g$. Furthermore, for any real $y \le -\inf(g)$, we have that $-y \ge \inf(g)$ so there exists $t$ such that $-y\ge g(t) \implies y\le -g(t)$ (so $y$ is not an upper bound of $-g$).
From this we deduce that $-\inf(g)$ is the smallest upper bound of $-g$ i.e. $-\inf(g) = \sup(-g) \,\,\, \blacksquare$